# Polymer 2.x - <paper-label> for something other than a <paper-input> element?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-elements

I have a dialog with some `<paper-input>` elements with labels, and one element which is not a `<paper-input>` but which I also want to provide an identical-looking label for.

I've tried various solutions, but none seem to give me an identical label that is correctly placed. For example, this code places the label on top of the `<div slot="input">` element:

```
<paper-input-container>
    <label slot="label">Location</label>
    <div slot="input">
        <img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=[[_position.lat]],[[_position.lng]]&zoom=16&size=200x125&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7label:%7C[[_position.lat]],[[_position.lng]]&key=MY_API_KEY">
        <paper-button on-tap="doStuff"><iron-icon icon="maps:place"></iron-icon> &nbsp; Pick location</paper-button>
    </div>
</paper-input-container>
```

The result isn't exactly what I'd hoped for:

[image]

Is there a way to get labels that look like the others (i.e. `Name`, `Description` and `Category`) when I don't have a `<paper-input>` present?

Comment: Taken from paper-input-container's implementation: "### Using a custom input element
You can use a custom input element in a `<paper-input-container>`, for example to implement a
compound input field like a social security number input. The custom input element should have the
`paper-input-input` class, have a `notify:true` value property and optionally implements
`Polymer.IronValidatableBehavior` if it is validatable." I'm hoping that just adding the `paper-input-input` class solves the problem, without having looked at the styles, let alone trying it myself.

Comment: @craPkit I missed that info in the doc - however, it doesn't work even with  `class="paper-input-input"`. The only thing that seems to do is change the `z-index` of  the label so it gets placed behind the image when I tap the `<paper-button>`...

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be easy enough to fix - I simply added `always-float-label` to the `<paper-input-container>` and things started working as expected.

```
<paper-input-container always-float-label>
    ...
</paper-input-container>
```

It seems that the reason I didn't need to add that to the other input elements is that they have their `placeholder` attributes set, which automatically makes the label "floating" (i.e. small and appearing above the input).